# Convert hh:mm:ss to minutes return but return TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Tags: pandas

Original data in a dataframe look like below and I want to convert it to minutes:

```
0         03:30:00
1              NaN
2         00:25:00
```

I learned a very good approach from this post: 
[Convert hh:mm:ss to minutes using python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17951820/convert-hhmmss-to-minutes-using-python-pandas)

`df2['FS_Runtime'].str.split(':')`   running this code split the data into below

```
0         [03, 30, 00]
1              NaN
2         [00, 25, 00]
```

I then added the .apply like the example in the post.

```
df2['FS_Runtime'].str.split(':').apply(lambda x: int(x[0])*60)
```

but i got the following error:

> TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because of NaN in the dataframe. You can try this

```
df1['FS_Runtime'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['FS_Runtime'], format = '%H:%M:%S')
df1['FS_Runtime'].dt.hour * 60 + df1['FS_Runtime'].dt.minute

0    210.0
1      NaN
2     25.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Your format is in the proper format for `pd.to_timedelta` then get the number of seconds and divide by 60:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pd.to_timedelta(df['FS_Runtime']).dt.total_seconds()/60
# Alternatively
pd.to_timedelta(df['FS_Runtime'])/np.timedelta64(1, 'm')

#0    210.0
#1      NaN
#2     25.0
#Name: FS_Runtime, dtype: float64
```