# Time Text to Secs and Milliseconds

Tags: python, pandas

I have a field in a data frame that has a string of time

```py
df['Time'] which equals 
01:21.46
```

what I would like to do is have that convert to secs and milliseconds so

81.46

I have tried to make a datetime but that has made more problems than good

There are other similar questions answered but I haven't seen with the milliseconds which is what I really need

Comment: What are the problems that you are facing? Please mention the errors you are getting.

Comment: Try `df['Time'].str.split(':').astype(float)`, then add the two columns that you get from this with the first column `* by 60`

Comment: I tried making the column a actual datetime field but I couldnt get that to work at all, and not sure that was the best approach, so hoping there might be something much easier that im missing

Comment: Hey @BharathM cheers for that, how would I get the two columns out ? and would that still maintain the milliseconds?

Comment: possible duplicate of [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17951820/convert-hhmmss-to-minutes-using-python-pandas)

Comment: @PIG , I really need to have the milliseconds and I couldnt find anything in that link regarding the decimals

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `datetime` for this,

```
def time_split(time_str):
    minute,second=time_str.split(":")
    if minute[0]==0:
        minute = minute[1]
    second,milisecond=second[0:2],second[2:]
    if second[0]==0:
        second = second[1]
    return int(minute),int(second),float(milisecond)

minute, second, milisecond = time_split("01:21.46")
total_seconds = minute * 60 + second + milisecond
```

Comment: Is it possible to have the milliseconds?

Comment: @RobPorter just added to the last line.

Comment: Sorry mate ... I was meaning the ability to keep milliseconds in the total... not sum them up

Comment: @RobPorter Updated, this should work.

Comment: ive just realised that some of the fields in the dataframe are NaN and thats breaking it when it runs into those blanks.  but it works perfectly on my test examples,

Comment: im sure im so close on this but im getting back an error of
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: @RobPorter If there are NaN values, I would suggest `try/except` block or control the argument in the `time_split` function whether it is NaN or not with `pd.isna`

Comment: I was able to populate the NaN with 00:00.00 but im still getting the too many value to unpack when i try

Comment: @RobPorter Can you give an example input for that error? Cause, it's already working fine for "01:21.46"

Comment: im trying to get a df field go into it ... its called df['Time']  so i have tried df['Time'].str etc but no luck it comes back with to many values to unpack... but it should be exactly like the example